# How to upload .csv file in Azure blob specific container and folder directory using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to upload a .csv file from local machine to Azure blob using power shell.
my objective is to upload the file in contianer and specific folder directory.
i dont want to overwrite the folder directory.

```
Import-Module AzureRM
#Connect-AzureRmAccount
$file = "C:\Junk\pso.csv"
$StorageAccountName = "datasourcedev"
$ContainerName = "landing-zone"
$BlobPath ="Temu_Test"
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -SASToken "<<SAS TOKEN>>"
#Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | Select StorageAccountName

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $file -Blob $BlobPath -Container $ContainerName -Context $context
```

I always need to upload a file into the existing "landing-zone\Temu_Test\pso.csv". my folder Temu_Test should not overwrite or recreate for every run.